# Plotly + Python: Easiest option to customize a Plotly graph in a Django template

Tags: python, django, plotly, plotly-python

I want to show several Plotly graphs on a Django page. I already have the Python lists with the data that I want to include in the graphs.

I found a code that works, but apparently it's old or strange (all the other Plotly code snippets that I see are very different) and I can't really customize it (trying to use lines/concepts from the "official" code snippets doesn't work with this old/strange code).

The code that works for me is:

```
from plotly.offline import plot
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter


plot_scatter = plot([Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data,
                        mode='lines', name='test',
                        opacity=0.8, marker_color='green')],
               output_type='div')

context = {
    'plot_scatter' : plot_scatter,
    OTHER STUFF
    }
    return render(request, 'hello/graphs.html', context)
```

That works, but then I want to reduce margins for example, and I find examples such as https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/ where the code is very different to "mine" and I can't adapt it (maybe there is a way, but I tried different options without any luck).

And the default code from Plotly (e.g.https://plotly.com/python/figure-structure/) is not designed to be used inside Django and I don't know how to adapt it to Django either.

I'm still learning Python, so maybe there is an obvious solution that I'm missing.

Any tips, ideas or links would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show several Plotly charts on a single Django page, you can use the following code in your views.py file for your Django app

```
def plot1():
    x_data = [0,1,2,3]
    y_data = [x**2 for x in x_data]
    plot_div = plot([Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data,
                        mode='lines+markers', name='test',
                        opacity=0.8, marker_color='green',)],
               output_type='div')
    return plot_div

def plot2():
    random_x = [100, 2000, 550]
    names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    fig = px.pie(values=random_x, names=names)
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=20, b=20), paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue")
    plot_div2 = plot(fig, output_type='div')
    return plot_div2

def index(request):
    plots = [
        plot1(),
        plot2(),
    ]
    return render(request, "hello/graphs.html", context={"plots": plots})
```

You can then use `fig.update` to update layout and further customise.

In your hello/graphs.html page you can then display each plot using a for loop, so you can display multiple graphs on a single page in Django

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  {% autoescape off %}
  {% for plot in plots %}
    {{plot}}
    
    {% endfor %}
  {% endautoescape %}
</body>
```

The graph sizes should be customised using Plotly however you might want to also double check the `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in your hello/graphs.html file.